# why is the pop function not popping the correct index?

Tags: python

input:

```
ls = ['hi', 'bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope']
ls_popped = []


i = 0
while i < 3:
    ls_popped.append(ls.pop(i))
    i += 1

print(ls)
print(ls_popped)
```

output:

```
['bye', 'hello']
['hi', 'bye', 'nope']
```

expected output:

```
['hello', 'nope']
['hi', 'bye', 'cya']
```

i believe the pop function pops and returns the element at index i, so it should pop from i = 0 to 2 and return these elements to the new list. im not sure why this is not working as expected.

Comment: After you pop the element at index 0, *the indexes of all other elements change*.  When you then pop index 1, that's the element that was originally at index 2, and so on.

Comment: This is a duplicate of iterating array while removing elements

Comment: @KavinduRavishka If you're talking about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating), that one is focused on the problems with `iter`-style iterators and for-each, which does cause big problems when removing elements. A `while` loop like OP is doing is perfectly safe; they just have to take care with the indices. One is a theoretical limitation with Python's `iter` interface, the other simply requires a bit of care on the part of the programmer.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo There is no difference between these two since in this code i is increased every time. Has  the same effect as iter

Comment: @SilvioMayolo only differece is this wont throw an index error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's trace it through. At the beginning of your program, we have

```
ls = ['hi', 'bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope']
ls_popped = []
i = 0
```

Now we run the loop once. We pop the element at position 0 and append it to `ls_popped`.

```
ls = ['bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope']
ls_popped = ['hi']
i = 1
```

Great! Now the loop variable is `1`. So we pop the thing at position 1. Note that that's *not* `bye`: `bye` is at 0 now, while `cya` is at 1.

```
ls = ['bye', 'hello', 'nope']
ls_popped = ['hi', 'cya']
i = 2
```

Now `i` is 2, so we're looking at position 2, which contains `nope`.

```
ls = ['bye', 'hello']
ls_popped = ['hi', 'cya', 'nope']
i = 3
```

Now `i` is 3 so the loop exits and we move on, printing the result

Answer (score 2):

It helps to see your list visually:

```
'hi', 'bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope'
-----------------------------------
 0       1      2       3       4
```

We start with the `while` loop at `0`, and extract the first element and put in `ls_popped`. When you extract the first element the remaining elements in `ls` shift, so visually it will look like:

```
'bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope'
-----------------------------
 0       1      2       3
```

Now `i` is increased to `1` and so you now extract `cya` and append it in the `ls_popped`.

`ls`:

```
'bye', 'hello', 'nope'
----------------------
 0       1        2
```

Now `i` is `2`, we so we extract `nope` and append it to `ls_popped`.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to break the list in parts is through slicing, not through a loop and `pop`:

```
ls = ['hi', 'bye', 'cya', 'hello', 'nope']
idx_cut = 3
ls_popped = ls[:idx_cut]
ls = ls[idx_cut:]
print(ls)
print(ls_popped)
# ['hello', 'nope']
# ['hi', 'bye', 'cya']
```

**SEE ALSO:**

- [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/967621)
- [Python tutorial: lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)